# \hrulefill at the beginning of the line

Tags: line

I'm trying to add two horizontal lines above some text, something like this

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\vspace{20mm}
\hfill \hfill\\
\hrulefill  \hfill \hrulefill\\
Date \hfill Signature
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the lines are not displayed.
If I add a letter before the first \hrulefill, the lines appear, unfortunately the letter as well.

I'm using TexWorks BTW.

Is there a way to add such a line without a letter in the leftmost part of the line?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please complete your code snippet to a full compilable document and tell us which tex engine you are using.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You seem to be misusing ``\\``.

Comment: What is wrong with \\ isn't that the command for a new line?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\centering
\hrulefill\\
text
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\centering
\hrulefill\\
other text
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `amsmath` package command `underset` and place an `mbox` under a line of length you determine. I made a new command called `\lineover` that takes two arguments. The first is the length of the line and the second is the text (or math if you use `$ .. $`). They are pushed to the edges of the page using the `\hfill` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\lineover}[2]{$\underset{\mbox{#2}}{\rule{#1}{1pt}}$}

\begin{document}

\noindent\lineover{4cm}{text}\hfill\lineover{4cm}{other text}

\bigskip
\noindent\lineover{1in}{$a=b$}\hfill\lineover{2in}{$a^2+b^2=c^2$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust the thickness of the line if you wish. I set it to `1pt`.

Comment: Sorry, but this if far away to be a robust solution. Math mode to produce the line is not good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\vspace{20mm}
\hfill \hfill\\
\phantom{}\hrulefill  \hfill \hrulefill\\
Date \hfill Signature
\end{document}
```

Are there any reasons against this solution?

Comment: See other solutions.

Comment: This will not center-justify your text.

Comment: +1 I'm coming to this much later with a similar problem and this is the answer that directly answers the question.  The other answers try to avoid the problem and might be better for the specific MWE in the question, but this is a general solution answering the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\vskip 2cm
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}{6cm}\centering%
    \hrulefill\par%
    Name
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is essentially the same solution as the one @tomacs already posted.

Comment: @SandyG, oh, yest. I post a solution without reading the others.

Comment: @SandyG well, I think tomacs deleted his solution, so I guess this is fine.